# Docusign Connect - Is there a way to configure webhook so that it posts data to my api with Content-Type "application/xml"?

Tags: docusignapi, webhooks

I have configured a Docusign webhook which is posting data to my service with Content-Type "text/xml" which is not supported by my service. Can i make any change so that webhook posts data with Content-Type "application/xml"?

Comment: WELCOME to StackOverflow! Please check/accept the best answer to each of your questions! THANK YOU!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you can not specify the Content-Type of webhook messages which currently is text/xml. There are plans to have JSON as an option but not for now